# I need to comment a file with exact pattern matching via shell script

Tags: regex, linux, shell

**I need to comment a file with exact pattern matching via shell script**

I have a file with some data like:

```
hello123
123hello
hello1
11hello
hello11
hello122
```

I need to comment a exact matching pattern line.

For example i need to comment "hello1" from the given file, after that the file content must be like

```
hello123
123hello
# hello1
11hello
hello11
hello122
```

avoid another line commenting, with normal pattern matching.

Comment: Don't change your question. I have rolled back your edit; accept the answer you got, and post a new question for the new problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may use sed..

```
sed 's/^hello1$/# &/' file
```

or

```
sed '/^hello1$/s/^/# /' file
```

Comment: Thank you Avinash, I have another question.

Comment: if you want the change to takesplace then add `-i` param like `

`sed -i 's/^hello1$/# &/' file`